# C# How to concatenate path and variable

Tags: c#, path, listbox

I want to display a different photo according to the text on the listBox. It will be about 1000 photos +.

The `listbox.text` will be the name of the picture(1, 2 ,3 etc).

I have no idea how to do that.

```
pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.(listBox2.Text);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) is the answer to post's title, but I doubt it is what you are looking for... Can you please clarify how "resources" in sample are related to title of your post?

Comment: are you storing your pictures into resources? or physical path?

Comment: Yes, I will store into resources.

Comment: Resources is a folder in my project in witch I'll store the pictures.

Comment: Can you please clarify which one should be title of your post: "load image from resource by name" OR "load image from known folder by file name" OR "how to get location of folder next to my executable to load images from"?

Comment: Echoing @AlexeiLevenkov's comment, please provide more details

Comment: load image from resource by name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want, you should get selected Item's text:

```
var imgName = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
pictureBox1.Image = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgName) as Bitmap;
```

Comment: Doesn't `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager` exist?

Comment: It says "WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources" does not contain a definition for "imgName".

Comment: +1: assuming the question is "load image from application resource by name" (may not be the case as it is unclear if OP adds all files from "resources" folder into actual resources of the app).

Comment: @user3131221 check my answer again and make sure your resource file name is correct and matching with your listBox items

Comment: pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgName) as Bitmap;

Comment: note: you don't have to specify fully qualified name. you can just do: `Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imgName) as Bitmap`

Comment: @user3131221 okey then, keep that way :-)

Answer (score -1):

A very handy thing to do with list boxes is to add objects to them.  The listbox displays the object's ToString() as the name of the object and you can then get the object directly using the SelectedItem property.  Something like this would do what you need:

```
namespace showimage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<ImagePicker> image_list;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            image_list = new List<ImagePicker>();

            // Add the images - creating an ImagePicker object per file
            image_list.Add(new ImagePicker("Photo1", "photo1.jpg"));
            image_list.Add(new ImagePicker("Photo2", "photo2.jpg"));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(image_list.ToArray());
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImagePicker picked_image = (ImagePicker)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            pictureBox1.Load(picked_image.filename);
        }
    }


    public class ImagePicker
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _filename;

        public string filename 
        {
            get 
            {
                return _filename;
            }
        }

        public ImagePicker(string name, string filename)
        {
            _name = name;
            _filename = filename;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
             return _name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: I don't see how this answers "load image from resource by name" OR "load image from known folder by file name" question...

Comment: Thank you for the answer neilcollins.

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear.  The Load on the picturebox is how you load an image from a filename.  I thought you were asking how to map a user readable name to a filename.  The above example shows you how to do that and hook off the Selected event which is what you need to do.